# Why does my laptop Bluray drive not read any discs?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, blu-ray

No disc put into my drive will read. If I double-click in My Computer it ejects and asks me to insert a disc. CD, DVD, Bluray, video, audio, or data. Same results.

I have an Asus N35SV laptop with Windows 7, Slimtype BD E DS4E1S model Bluray drive.

I've checked their website which has no driver. I found them elsewhere and installed the newest and previous to that drivers in various ways. Tried Windows Update. Nothing works.

Comment: Perhaps its a faulty optical drive?

Comment: @Antp Possibly, it's around 2 years old. I've played Blurays on it before no problems. I feel like a blank disc would show up but I can't remember and I don't have any lying around at the moment.

Comment: perhaps try a mates optical drive or buy a cheepy on ebay.

Comment: Have you tried this drive on other computers? Maybe it's just not compatible with your computer.

Answer (score 1):

If you've tried all the discs, and none of them is working. You may try changing the location once.

Right Click on My computer

Click Manage

Go to Device Manager

Right click on Optical Drive and go to properties

Click on Region

By default i'll show no region selected, Change it to US, i'll show a binary value 1, save the changes, further check if it works